# custom a tooltipContent of tooltips with datum in discreteBarChart nvd3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, nvd3.js

How I can custom a tooltipContent of tooltips using data loaded into "datum" in discreteBarChart nvd3.js?, for example, with the following data Jason, I want to see data3, data4, Data5 in tooltips

```
JsonData = [ 
             {
               key: "Serie1",
               values: [
                         {'Data1':  1, 
                          'Data2':  2, 
                          'Data3':  3,
                          'Data4':  4,
                          'Data5':  5
                         }
                       ]
             }
           ];
```

Comment: This is a contribution

Comment: Ok, thanks and sorry.
now change the post.

Answer (score 7):

This is how to do it:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {  
   var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.Data1 })
      .y(function(d) { return d.Data2 })
      .tooltips(true)
      .tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
       var data =graph.series.values[y-1];
       return  '<p> Text1: ' +  data.Data3 + '</p>'
             + '<p> Text2: ' +  data.Data4 + '</p>'
             + '<p> Text3: ' +  data.Data5 + '</p>'
       });

   d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(JsonData)
      .call(chart);

   nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

   return chart;
});
```

Comment: In my case the trick was: `graph.point.x`, `graph.point.y`, `graph.point.anything`.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with something like this, since the graph object has a value attribute:

```
chart.tooltipContent(function (key, date, e, graph) {
     var value = graph.value;
     return  "<p><strong>" + date + "</strong><br>" + value + "</p>";
});
```

No need for accessing the series-array I guess.